# Mutate Frequency table using dplyr- R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am new to using dplyr and need some help. I have a frequency (number) table (long format). Here is some sample data:

```
dput(test_data)
structure(list(ref = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 15L, 15L
), Status = c("status1", "status2", "status3", "status1", 
"status2", "status3", "status1", "status2", "status3"), value = c(1718L, 
0L, 0L, 576L, 24L, 0L, 224L, 104L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to create a frequency distribution column and replace "value" column. For example, I want to sum all the "Sensor_Status" values when "Sensor_Status=sensor1" and divide the values column that correspond to "Sensor_Status=sensor1" . In this test data, sum(sensor1-values) will be 2518 and row1-column3 value will be 1718/2518. Sum of all frequencies of sensor1 should add to 1. Any help is appreciated.
I am looking for a output table like this:

```
structure(list(conc = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 15L, 15L
), Sensor_Status = c("status1", "status2", "status3", "status1", 
"status2", "status3", "status1", "status2", "status3"), value = c(1718L, 
0L, 0L, 576L, 24L, 0L, 224L, 104L, 3L), prop = c(0.682287529785544, 
0, 0, 0.228752978554408, 0.1875, 0, 0.0889594916600477, 0.8125, 
1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Could you please show the expected output?

Comment: Thank you @TarJae, I added the output I am looking for. I do not know how to copy a table, I used dput() of my desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Sensor_Status) %>%
  mutate(prop = value/sum(value)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 9 x 4
    ref Sensor_Status value   prop
  <int> <chr>         <int>  <dbl>
1     5 status1        1718 0.682 
2     5 status2           0 0     
3     5 status3           0 0     
4    10 status1         576 0.229 
5    10 status2          24 0.188 
6    10 status3           0 0     
7    15 status1         224 0.0890
8    15 status2         104 0.812 
9    15 status3           3 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty confused that you keep talking about "sensor1" but I don't see that in the data--I assume you mean `Sensor_Status == "status1"`.

My best guess is that you want to add two columns: 1 is the `sum(value)` grouped by `Sensor_Status`, and the other is each individual `value` divided by the grouped sum. (If you name one of these added columns `value`, it will overwrite the existing `value` column. I'll keep the old column around to make it easier to see what's happening.)

```
library(dplyr)
test_data %>%
  group_by(Sensor_Status) %>%
  mutate(sum = sum(value),
         proportion = value / sum) %>%
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 9 × 5
    ref Sensor_Status value   sum proportion
  <int> <chr>         <int> <int>      <dbl>
1     5 status1        1718  2518     0.682 
2     5 status2           0   128     0     
3     5 status3           0     3     0     
4    10 status1         576  2518     0.229 
5    10 status2          24   128     0.188 
6    10 status3           0     3     0     
7    15 status1         224  2518     0.0890
8    15 status2         104   128     0.812 
9    15 status3           3     3     1
```

Comment: Thank you @GregorThomas, sorry for the confusing text. You interpreted it correctly. I will change the wording in the question. This is the solution I was looking for.